# Showing images in ios webView not working

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview

Im having some problems with showing an imagelink on ios webbView. What's happening is that I've put down a webView in my xib file and connected it with outlet but i stil can't get the image to show up..

The code in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *urlLink = @"http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={FDCE3A18-B5F6-45F4-B9B2-EA9171290F71}&period=&week=41&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=844&height=629&maxwidth=844&maxheight=629";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLink];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

If someone could figure out what the problem is i'd be grateful!

Best regards Oliver

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=png&schoolid=90645/sv-se&type=1&id={FDCE3A18-B5F6-45F4-B9B2-EA9171290F71}&period=&week=41&mode=0&printer=0&colors=32&head=0&clock=0&foot=0&day=0&width=844&height=629&maxwidth=844&maxheight=629
```

This is not a direct link to an image. That's probably your issue. Try using a normal image link like this `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png` and it should show up.

Comment: I know that the link doesn't have a prefix after it, but this is the link i get when trying to copy the image link with google chrome.

Comment: Yes they do, i tried out to link it to google for an example, and it worked fine ;)

Comment: You might have some bad formatting in the url. Try this:
`urlLink = [urlLink  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: I have reformatted it, and done an nslog that shows that the string is correct, but somewhere in the conversion to an url everything goes wrong.